# Django debugging with Eclipse and PyDev

Tags: python, django, eclipse

I just managed to get debugging my django site 'kind of' working in Eclipse. All my breakpoints get caught just fine, but I have to restart the server every time I make a code change. I think this is because I'm using the --noreload argument when kicking off the server.

Is there any way to setup Eclipse debugging so that I can change code, and continue execution, with my changes being reflected in the django site straight away?

Cheers,
Dave

Trindaz on Fedang #django

Answer (score 2):

This *is* a bit late, but in case someone else comes looking for a solution to the same problem:

This [video](http://vimeo.com/5027645) was very helpful when I was trying to setup Django Eclipse debugging with `autoreload` i.e. without using the `--noreload` switch. It pretty much walks you through the steps with a couple of helpful pointers. I've set up twice myself using this video.

The `manage.py` replacement code can be obtained from http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1561/

I found these links through the poster's blog post which seems to be down at the moment, hence the direct links

*EDIT*: A patch may be required to Django 1.3 to run in `autoreload` mode from inside an IDE. See [PyCharm manage.py runserver error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110168/pycharm-manage-py-runserver-error) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

http://bear330.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/how-to-debug-django-web-application-with-autoreload/

Author explains how to do so here, basically you have to embed the remote debugger into your manage.py file.

Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome! No time to check this today but it'll be the first thing I check when I get back to Eclipse.

--Trindaz on Fedang

Comment: Thanks Mike but the solution didn't work for me. I noticed quite a few other commenters on the blog had trouble with it too. --Trindaz on Fedang #django